# How to check MX/SOA rcords for some sites

Tags: dns, bind

I world like to find MX for some web sites.

I tried something like www.yahoo.com  MX IN 
but I cannot find mail.yahoo.com

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ dig yahoo.com MX
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> yahoo.com MX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20645
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;yahoo.com.         IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
yahoo.com.      269 IN  MX  1 mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com.      269 IN  MX  1 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com.      269 IN  MX  1 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.

;; Query time: 64 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar  9 18:51:14 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 106
```